# SAS output confidence interval to plot for strata variable after logistic regression

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

I want to put all confidence interval plot in one plot for all strata variable after logistic regression. For example, my SAS code is:

```
proc logistic data=data1;
model y = x;
strata cv1;
output out=out1 unknown1=x_beta1 unknown2=lowerbound unknown3=upperbound unknown4=strata_variable;
run;
```

I do not know what variable names(unknown1 unknown2 unknown3) I can use in the output statement. As in the sas support page, it said "If a STRATA statement is specified, only the PREDICTED=, DFBETAS=, and H= options are available",here is the  [link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect012.htm).

My plot statement will be:

```
proc sgplot data=out1;
  scatter y=strata_variable x=x_beta1 / xerrorlower=lowerbound xerrorupper=upperbound
          markerattrs=(symbol=circlefilled size=9);
  run;
```

The first plot in this [page](http://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/2012/01/12/custom-confidence-intervals/) shows exactly what I want. Sorry I cannot insert any plot as my reputation is not high enough.

Comment: Have you tried proc surveylogistic instead?

Answer (score 0):

I find an another way to finish this. I wrote a macro do loop to get every strata data. And then added

```
ods output OddsRatios=odds_temp;
```

to get the estimation and confidence interval and merger all the strata together to make the plot I need.